# the solution of $|x|^{x^2-x-2} < 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I have tried it using log of $|x|$ which gives RHS value 0 and LHS gives quadratic equation of $x^2-x-2$ and solving it i get value of x between - 1 to 2 EXCEPT 0 but answer is $x$ between (1,2).

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $|x|>1\iff x>1\  \ \  \ (1)$ or $x<-1\  \ \  \ (2)$

we need $0>x^2-x-2=(x-2)(x+1)\iff -1<x<2\  \ \  \ (3)$

Find the intersection of $(1),(3)$ and $(2),(3)$

If $|x|<1\iff-1<x<1\  \ \  \ (4)$

we need  $x^2-x-2>0\implies$ either $x>2\  \ \  \ (5)$ or $x<-1\  \ \  \ (6)$

Find the intersection of $(4),(5)$ and $(4),(6)$

Comment: also consider $x\neq 0$:)

Comment: @daulomb, Observe that the intersections of $(1),(3)$ and $(2),(3)$  are null set. Why should we consider $x=0$ separately?

Comment: sorry I am trying to understand why $x=0$ is included

Comment: @daulomb, I have included $$|x|> <1$$ only as we need to test for $><1$

Comment: I had a confusion with the other answer because in that  $x=0$ is accepted as a solution but now I am okey

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient covert the inequality by logarithm (since log function is monotonically increasing):

$$|x|^{x^2-x-2} < 1\iff (x^2-x-2)\log |x|<0$$

Then it is convenient eliminate the absolute value considering 2 cases:

1) $x>0$ $\implies(x^2-x-2)\log x<0$

2) $x<0$ $\implies(x^2-x-2)\log (-x)<0 \implies y^2+y-2 \log y <0 \quad y=-x>0$

You can find the solution for each case by studing the sign of $x^2-x-2$, $x^2+x-2$ and $\log x$.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to:
$$|x|^{x^2-x-2}<|x|^0$$
It is equivalent to:
$$1) \begin{cases} |x|>1 \\ x^2-x-2<0 \end{cases} \ \ \text{OR} \ \ 2) \begin{cases} 0<|x|<1 \\ x^2-x-2>0 \end{cases}.$$
Can you solve the two systems and unite their solutions?